# Change Favorably of random intergers from math.random

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
public void onFinish() {
              int num;
              String outCome = "";
              for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
                  num = (int) (Math.random() * 100) % 3;

                  switch (num) {
                  case 0:
                      outCome = "ountcome1";
                      break;
                  case 1:
                      outCome = "outcome2";
                      break;
                  case 2:
                      outCome = "outcome3";
                      break;
             }
                text.setText(outCome);
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that case 0 has a %50 chance to happen, while case 1 and 2 have %25 chance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `Random.nextInt(4)` and in cases 0,3 return "ountcome1".
In case 1 return "ountcome2" and in case 2 return "ountcome3":

```
            switch (num) {
              case 0:
              case 3:
                  outCome = "outcome1";
                  break;
              case 1:
                  outCome = "outcome2";
                  break;
              case 2:
                  outCome = "outcome3";
                  break;
              ...
```

Comment: So add another case then make 0 and 1 the same?

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a `double` which is why you have to cast it to int - that's not the correct way of using it. Use `nextInt(4)` and then you have 25% for each on of the numbers: `[0,1,2,3]` so you can treat `0` and `1` as the "first" 50% etc.

Comment: public void onFinish() {
           int num;
           String outCome = "";
           for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
            num = (int) (Random.nextInt(4);
            switch (num) {
            case 0:
             outCome = "outcome1";
             break;
            case 1:
             outCome = "outcome2";
             break;
            case 2:
             outCome = "outcome2";
             break;
      case 3:
             outCome = "outcome3";
             break;
                 }
          text.setText(outCome);
             }

Comment: @Cflinspach posting code like you did in a comment is not readable. Better update your question! See updated code snippet in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
  for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
              num = (int) (Math.random() * 100) % 4; //Use 4 instead of 3

              switch (num) {
              case 0:
                  outCome = "ountcome1";
                  break;
              case 1:
                  outCome = "outcome2";
                  break;
              case 2:
                  outCome = "outcome3";
                  break;
              case 3:
                  outCome = "ountcome1";
                  break;

         }
```

Thus here there are four possible outcomes. If 0 or 3 are obtained, you output ountcome1 (50% probability) else the other two.

Comment: its not garenty to generte outcome 1 by 50%

Comment: there are only four possible outcomes here. 0,1,2, and 3 in random chance ( each equiprobable: 25% chance). If 0 or 3 are obtained we are outputting outcome 1. So thereby a 50% chance.

Comment: Funny, it looks familiar, wait - that's my answer - only that I wrote it 5 minutes before you...

Comment: No, you are using **nextint**, while I have used the **same** thing he used, changing only the divisor. So in case you downvoted my answer, please note that.

Answer (score -1):

try to use this

```
public void onFinish() {
          int num;
          String outCome = "";
          for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {


              Random x = new Random(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMilliSec());
              num = x.nextInt(4);
              switch (num) {
              case 0:
                  outCome = "ountcome1";
                  break;
              case 1:
                  outCome = "outcome2";
                  break;
              case 2:
                  outCome = "outcome3";
                  break;
              case 3:
                  outCome = "ountcome1";
                  break;
         }
            text.setText(outCome);
```

Comment: why has my answer being voted down can anyone explain

Comment: No it won't, the OP asked 50% for 0 then 25% for 1 and 25% for 2. That's not what you implemented.

Comment: I think this would give 50% wieghtage to outcome one an 25, 25 % to outcome 2 and outcome 3 respectively

Comment: This last fix should work - only that the switch's body is an exact copy of Gautham's solution...